# Create table from JSON API Request

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests, python-3.6

I'm sending a JSON query with request module. I really need to store data in a csv-file based on requests.models.Response as picture attached.

Problem I'm facing is the relationships between columns and to store it in the right structure as picture. Is it possible to create this in Python based on Output(request_text)?

Script:

```
import re
import requests


r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
request_text = r.text

# split everything on '\r\n'
newtext = request_text.split('\r\n')

#loop through text to create list
lst = list()
for line in newtext:
    lst.append(line) 


# view longest column values    
lst[56:72]
# create first list 2014 and 2015
list1 = list()
list2 = list()
for item in lst[56:72]:
    a = re.findall("[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?", item)
    list1.append(a[0])
    list2.append(a[1])

#create longest column for csv-table
valueslist = list1 + list2    

#check length of columns 
length1 = len(list1)
length2 = len(list2)   

#map city to same structure
b = str(lst[16:17])
#Get city names
c = b.split("=")[1].split(";")[0]
#split city names
d = c.split(',')
#create list for city names
lst = list()
for item in d:
    lst.append(item)
#append city to match output as many times as len above for values 1
list3 = list()
for i in range(length1):
    list3.append(lst[0])
#append city to match output as many times as len above for values 2
for i in range(length2):
    list3.append(lst[1])
#same len    
len(valueslist)
len(list3)   

#two columns ready for csv writerow
valueslist
list3
```

Output(request_text):

```
CHARSET="ANSI";
AXIS-VERSION="2010";
CODEPAGE="iso-8859-1";
LANGUAGE="sv";
CREATION-DATE="20171003 21:15";
DECIMALS=0;
SHOWDECIMALS=0;
MATRIX="BE0101N2";
COPYRIGHT=NO;
SUBJECT-CODE="BE";
SUBJECT-AREA="Befolkning";
TITLE="Folkökning efter region, civilstånd, ålder, kön, tabellinnehåll och år";
CONTENTS="Folkökning";
STUB="region","civilstånd","ålder","kön";
HEADING="tabellinnehåll","år";
CONTVARIABLE="tabellinnehåll";
VALUES("region")="Finspång","Valdemarsvik";
VALUES("civilstånd")="ogifta","gifta";
VALUES("ålder")="60-64 år","65-69 år";
VALUES("kön")="män","kvinnor";
VALUES("tabellinnehåll")="Folkökning";
VALUES("år")="2014","2015";
TIMEVAL("år")=TLIST(A1),"2014","2015";
CODES("region")="0562","0563";
CODES("civilstånd")="OG","G";
CODES("ålder")="60-64","65-69";
CODES("kön")="1","2";
CODES("tabellinnehåll")="BE0101N2";
CODES("år")="2014","2015";
PRESTEXT("region")=2;
PRESTEXT("år")=0;
ELIMINATION("kön")=YES;
UNITS="antal";
LAST-UPDATED("Folkökning")="20170214 15:50";
STOCKFA("Folkökning")="F";
DAYADJ("Folkökning")=NO;
SEASADJ("Folkökning")=NO;
UNITS("Folkökning")="antal";
CONTACT("Folkökning")="Tomas Johansson, Statistiska centralbyrån (SCB)# Telefon: +46 010-479 64 26#Fax: +46 #e-post: tomas.johansson@scb.se#(SCB) Statistikservice, Statistiska centralbyrån (SCB)# Telefon: +46 010-479 48 01#Fax: +46 #e-post: information@scb.se";
DATABASE="Statistikdatabasen 2.3";
SOURCE="Statistiska centralbyrån (SCB)";
INFOFILE="BE0101";
NOTEX="Fr o m 2007-01-01 överförs Heby kommun från Västmanlands län till Uppsala län. Hebys kommunkod ändras från 1917 till 0331. ##Registrerat partnerskap reglerade parförhållanden mellan personer av samma kön och fanns från 1995 till 2009. Registrerade partne"
"rs räknas som Gifta, Separerade partners som Skilda och Efterlevande partners som Änka/änklingar.";
NOTE="Folkökningen definieras som skillnaden mellan folkmängden vid årets början och årets slut.";
META-ID("civilstånd")=" ";
META-ID("ålder")=" ";
META-ID("kön")="Kön";
DATASYMBOL1=".";
DATASYMBOL2="..";
DATASYMBOL3="..";
DATASYMBOLSUM="*";
DATASYMBOLNIL="-";
DATANOTESUM="*";
TABLEID="TAB638";
DATA=
-2 6 
-3 8 
18 9 
11 5 
-16 -39 
-7 -12 
4 -20 
-14 1 
2 -1 
10 -7 
-2 -4 
-3 4 
-12 -27 
-33 -22 
-20 2 
20 -4 
;
```

Cheers,
Johan

[Wanted CSV output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgJUj.png)

Comment: What have you tried to solve this so far?

Comment: @Klaus D. I have tried regex on string then place everything in a list where I slice to create each column. Before creating a for loop iterating each column as many times as largest column to create csv-output. Don't know if there is a module/technique to do this more smoothly? I'm I way off? Thx

Comment: Please add some of your code!

Comment: @Klaus D does python have an easier and more dynamic way of doing this? I'm new to python and don't understand the best approach for this. All feedback is much appreciated. thx

Comment: @Klaus D added some more code above